# getScript or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get Javascript data in another page and use it in an existing javascript.

Let me explain it with the codes.

I want to get this data from that other page

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var data = {
  "users": [
    {
      "latitude": "48.405163",
      "longitude": "2.684659"
    },
    {
      "latitude": "43.7347242529278",
      "longitude": "7.42198348045349"
    }
  ]
};
    </script>
```

I tried to get it it using this code

```
    $(function MapData() {
        $.getScript({
            type: "GET",
            url: "default.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckinMap",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#content").append(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#content").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

In order to use data inside the data variable it in this code

```
  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.404840395764175, 2.6845264434814453);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
      var location = data.users[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,
          location.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But I am getting **data is not defined** error.

I also tried getting data from the other page using

`$.getScript('default.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckinMap');`

But I got the same error.

How can I fix this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're loading javascript with `$.getScript()`, you should not include `<script>` tags in the file you're loading. Also, you need to run your `initialize()` function **after** you've finished loading the file:

```
$.getScript('default.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckinMap', initialize)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I didnt really understand what you say here.

Answer (score 0):

data is available only for the call back function of the getScript call.
If you want to use it outside, store it in a global variable and use it.

Comment: its not inside a function in the other page doesnt that mean that it is a global variable in this case? If not, what do I need to do?